# Word to mean "make smaller by collision"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a paper talking about collisions during the formation of rocky planets.  Some of these collisions lead to an increase in mass (i.e., the largest body to come out of a collision is more massive than either of the two bodies that were involved in the collision) and some collisions lead to a decrease in mass (i.e., the largest body to come out of a collision is less massive than either of the two bodies that were involved in the collision.  I want a word to describe the second case, that the collision led to things getting smaller.

So far I have been using the word "erode" and its various forms, but "erode" means to make smaller over course of time, which doesn't match the situation I am trying to describe.  Collisions are discrete (rather than continuous) events, and occur relatively quickly, such that the mass loss is nearly instantaneous.  What would be a good word to describe this?

Comment: What word do you use for increase?

Comment: @J.Taylor increase and growth, sometimes (particular for collisions that lead to complete mergers of the two bodies) coalesce or merge

Comment: Consider "fragmentation", "disintegration" or "disaggregation".

Comment: Collision-grown and collision-reduced. Or collision-gained mass and collision-lost mass.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a ***spallation*** process.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spallation)

> Spallation is a process in which fragments of material (spall) are
>   ejected from a body due to impact or stress.

In the case the OP describes, both bodies undergo extensive spallation.  The result is a mess of debris and one (or possibly more than one) largish body, all of which are smaller than either of the originals.

Answer (score 1):

The word [***smash***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/smash) would fit very closely. From Oxford Dictionaries:

> 1. *[with object]* Violently break (something) into pieces:
>
> > 1. 1 *[no object]* Be violently broken into pieces; shatter:

and also

> 2. *[no object, with adverbial of direction]* Move so as to hit or collide with something with great force and impact

Your objects are being *smashed* into pieces in sense 1 as a result of *smashing into* one another in sense 2.

---

The term is a little on the informal side, but it fits your needs closely enough that I think it could easily be used and would seem natural in-context. (There is a history of informal words being used with a technical definition in scientific terminology, as for example [*fuzzy* mathematics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_mathematics) or [particle *strangeness*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strangeness), so maybe you could even define a new term.)

Answer (score 1):

If *increase* is used for a particle becoming larger, then

> The particle (or body) was diminished by the impact

or

> The particle (or body) was decreased by the impact.

That keeps things simple, and that is usually good.

Comment: But in the case of a particularly nasty collision, there is a lot of fragmentation and not really a body after the collision that I can say is the same body as the one before the collision, just smaller.

Comment: I think I understand that, Joshua. A apologize for not immediately catching the query beyond "two bodies". .